# EF code first InsertOrUpdate with return T

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I currently have a code which inserts or updates and return the affected entity
but for now it is returning a specific type

```
public delegate void BeforeTransaction(tbl_purchases_record x);

public static tbl_purchases_record insertupdate(
        tbl_purchases_record param,
        DB context, 
        Func<tbl_purchases_record,bool> lambda,
        BeforeTransaction beforetransaction = null)
 {

        var entity = context.tbl_purchases_record.SingleOrDefault(lambda);

        beforetransaction?.Invoke(entity); // callable parameter

        if (entity == null)
        {
            entity = context.tbl_purchases_record.Add(param);
        } 
        else
        {
            context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(param);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
        return entity;
    }
```

is it possible to make this return dynamic type?
*(Also wanna ask...if is this a bad practice?)*

Comment: I'd refrain from dynamic whenever possible. Why not make the method generic? `TEntity InsertOrUpdate<TEntity>`

Comment: Yes i can do that.. but my problem is context.tbl_purchases_record.SingleOrDefault(lambda)...i try context.Set(typeof(TEntity)) but this doesn't have SingleOrDefault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> Yes i can do that.. but my problem is context.tbl_purchases_record.SingleOrDefault(lambda)...i try context.Set(typeof(TEntity)) but this doesn't have SingleOrDefault

When using a generic method, the correct syntax to use is:

```
context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault();
```

You simply pass the generic parameter.

Putting it all together:

```
public T InsertUpdate<T>(T obj, DB context, Func<T,bool> lambda)
{
     var entity = context.Set<T>().SingleOrDefault(lambda);

    if (entity == null)
    {
        entity = context.Set<T>().Add(obj);
    } 
    else
    {
        context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(obj);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
    return entity;
}
```

Also note that in newer versions of EF, there is actually an `AddOrUpdate` method that does the same thing:

```
context.Set<T>().AddOrUpdate(
                     lambda,       //How to identify a pre-existing item
                     obj           //The item with new values
                );
```

It will do the same thing. If it finds a pre-existing item, it will update it. Otherwise it will create a new item. **However, this will not return the created/updated item** and is therefore probably not what you want to use here.

Comment: is EF AddOrUpdate will return the affected row?

Comment: i also want to execute something before it will do insert or update

Comment: @Arianne: `AddOrUpdate` does not return the object, so I'll add that caveat to my answer.

Comment: @Arianne: I skipped the `BeforeTransaction` because (1) it's not part of the actual question/answer and (2) I don't have enough information on it to understand it. Of course you can add this back in when implementing the code in your codebase.

Comment: Im very sorry for the `BeforeTransaction`. but your answer actually help me thank you :)..